# Sequelize Multiple nested Op.or operations

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is it possible to do multiple Op.or operations?

When I do

```
    [Op.and]: {
        [Op.or]: [{x: 1}, {x: 1}],
        [Op.or]: [{y}, {y}]
    }
```

The second Op.or overwrites the first one. Is there any way to do a (x or x) AND (y or y) operation?

Comment: May be related to [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11588).

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the general
(a or b) and (c or d) this translates for boolean algebra as:

```
(a + b) (c + d) = a (c + d) + b (c + d)
```

so

```js
[Op.or]: [
  { [Op.and]: [
      { [Op.or]: [
        {c}, {d}
      ] }, 
      {a}
  ] }, 
  { [Op.and]: [
    { [Op.or]: [
      {c}, 
      {d}
    ] }, 
    {b}
  ] }
]
```

Yeah I know... hopefully as Ouroborus mentioned via that issue above, it will be fixed.